# TypeError: input.setFocus is not a function when I run all Jasmine unit tests associated with the Angular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

With a `@ViewChild` decorator I grab the `ion-input` element to set focus with the `setFocus()` method. And this works as expected. I don't know why, but I can't figure out why all the Jasmine unit tests of the component fails. I've tried mocking the `setFocus()` method, but without success. Can anyone help me with this and know what I'm doing wrong?

Template with the `@ViewChild` reference `#input_username`

```
  <ion-input id="inputusername"
                 #input_username
                 color="dark"
                 role="textbox"
                 aria-label=""
                 class="input"
                 placeholder=""
                 type="text"
                 formControlName="name"
                 ngDefaultControl>
   </ion-input>
```

Component method that sets the focus with `setFocus()`

```
private _setFocusDefaultInput(input: ElementRef): void {
    const ionInput = input['el']; // get the DOM element from Ionic
    ionInput.setFocus();
}
```

The `_setFocusDefaultInput()` method is called inside the `ngAfterViewInit()` method

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this._setFocusDefaultInput(this.inputUsername); 
    }, 800);
  }
```

Error message I get when I run ALL the Jasmine unit tests that belongs to this component:

```
Failed: input.setFocus is not a function
    error properties: Object({ longStack: 'TypeError: input.setFocus is not a function
        at LoginPage._setFocusDefaultInput (src/app/login/login/login.page.ts:123:11)
        at src/app/login/login/login.page.ts:54:12
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:429:1)
        at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1231:33)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:328:43)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:428:1)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:307:88)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (nod ...
    TypeError: input.setFocus is not a function
```

I'v tried to mock the `setFocus()` method with the following code, but without success

TestBed configuration

```
  {
    provide: ElementRef,
    useClass: ElementRefMock
  },
  {
    provide: IonInput,
    useClass: IonInputMock
  }
```

Mocking classes

```
class ElementRefMock {
   setFocus(){}
   el: {
   setFocus: () => {}
   };
 }

class IonInputMock {
  setFocus(){}
  el: {
  setFocus: () => {}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking that each individual test runs faster than the timeout of 800ms and so the view of the input is destroyed but you still want to refer to it about 800ms later. Let's say a test took 200ms, 600ms the focus logic runs but within the 200ms the view has been destroyed and we are referring to something that does not exist.

Try this to debug:

```
private _setFocusDefaultInput(input: ElementRef): void {
    const ionInput = input['el']; // get the DOM element from Ionic
    // See what you get for the ionInput
    console.log(ionInput);
    // If ionInput is undefined, put a question mark between the . and setFocus
    // This way, it won't run if ionInput is undefined or null
    // You can of course put an if check as well.
    ionInput?.setFocus();
}
```

Comment: How could I not have noticed this before! This solves the problem, thanks. BUT I found a better solution that does NOT use the setTimeout method to set the focus.

Comment: I will add my new implementation as new answer

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer solved my problem, but I have found a new solution that no longer needs the setTimeout method to set the focus correctly on the Ionic input field. The Jasmine unit test issue I ran into have also been resolved with this implementation

1. I replaced the `ElementRef` interface with the `IonInput` interface to directly call `setFocus()`:

   ```
     @ViewChild('input_username') inputUsername: IonInput;
   ```
2. I implemented the `ionViewDidEnter()` Ionic lifecycle method. This method is not called until all Ionic elements have been successfully rendered into the DOM. That's when I want to set the focus on the Ionic input field:

   ```
     ionViewDidEnter(): void {
       this.inputUsername.setFocus();
     }
   ```